# Can I return JSON Web Token (JWT) through django-rest-auth login and registration?

Tags: django, jwt, django-rest-auth

I am trying to return JWT from my rest API through django-rest-auth but it gives a different type of token like for eg. `9054f7aa9305e012b3c2300408c3dfdf390fcddf`. 

I have my own TokenObtainPairSerializer for JWT like this:

`class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        email = user.email
        token = super(MyTokenObtainPairSerializer, cls).get_token(user)
        # Add custom claims
        token['first_name'] = user.first_name
        token['last_name'] = user.last_name
        token['email'] = user.email
        return token`


I would like the  `django-rest-auth`  to return my custom JWT through the login.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
P.S: I searched through google and other stack-overflow questions, but couldn't find what I'm actually looking for.

Comment: Did you try to decode the token? It should have the details you have provided in the token.

Comment: @sonus21 This token provided by django is actually, only for accessing the APIs. What I wanted to implement was, return the JWT instead of the django's built-in token.

Comment: If you have `MyTokenObtainPairSerializer` and you have JWT then it should work. Did you enable JWT ?

Comment: I was looking for a way to use JWT with the Django-rest-auth and failed. Is there any other options that I can use to return the JWT through Django-rest-auth?

Comment: What did fail? This is a sample to add that.

Comment: I used something like this in settings.py:

REST_AUTH = {
    'REST_AUTH_TOKEN_MODEL' : 'JWT',
    'REST_USE_JWT':True,
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215925/discussion-between-anjaan-and-sonus21).

Answer (score 1):

to use JWT with django rest_auth, you'd have to set the following config in the `settings.py`:

```
    REST_USE_JWT = True
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [ 
              'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication', 
        ], 
     }
```

Also remember to install `rest_framework_jwt` and add to your `INSTALLED_APPS`

UPDATE 2023:
I use simple jwt these days so an updated version would be:

```
#---------- REST FRAMEWORK Settings-----------
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
            'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [ 
               'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication', 
            ], 
         }
```